# Perl, length of sprintf generated string wrong?

Tags: perl, printf

I am creating a string which needs to be padded out by spaces to the maximum length of each field like so:

```
my $string;

$string .= sprintf("%*s", $fieldlength->{FOO}, uc( $foo ) );
$string .= sprintf("%*s", $fieldlength->{BAR}, uc( $bar ) );
```

This is within a loop for a bunch of records.
When I write $string to a file it looks exactly how I expect, everything in the right place. When I print the length of the $string it's wrong?

```
my $string;

$string .= sprintf("%*s", $fieldlength->{FOO}, uc( $foo ) );
warn length($string);
$string .= sprintf("%*s", $fieldlength->{BAR}, uc( $bar ) );
warn length($string);
```

In this example say `$fieldlength->{FOO}` is `100`, the warn returns `40`. I must be doing something stupid.

Ideally I'd like a sort of ruler as a first line marking * where each field should be. Since I can't seem to accuratly report where this is I'm stuck

Comment: both warns return 40?

Comment: Looks good from here.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem, it works just as expected when 100 is inserted. Most likely, the error is that the hash does not contain the number you think it does, so try also printing the `$fieldlength->{FOO}` values.

Comment: This question cannot be answered in its current state and will/should soon be put on hold, unless you update it with the requested information, Dr.Avalanche.

Comment: For reasons unknown this was failing on one server, having switched to another server I can't reproduce the weirdness. Same OS, patch level, Perl version. Our admins have taken the server out of production. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce. The following gives the correct value even as far back as 5.8.8.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fieldlength;
$fieldlength->{FOO} = 100;
$fieldlength->{BAR} = 200;

my $foo = "foo";
my $bar = "bar";

my $string;
$string .= sprintf("%*s", $fieldlength->{FOO}, uc( $foo ) );
$string .= sprintf("%*s", $fieldlength->{BAR}, uc( $bar ) );

print(length($string), "\n");  # 300
```

It's far more likely to be a problem with your code than a bug in Perl. Your values aren't what you think they are, etc. Rather than claiming a variable contains a value, show us you giving the variable that value. Rather than saying the output is something it isn't, show us the actual output, etc.

Comment: For reasons unknown this was failing on one server, having switched to another server I can't reproduce the weirdness. Same OS, patch level, Perl version. Our admins have taken the server out of production. Sorry for the trouble.